# Setting timeout for pollenrich using configuration property

Tags: apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I am using pollenrich in my code to get the message from the queue:

```
<pollEnrich uri="activemq:queueName" timeout="5000"/>
```

Now, I want to read the timeout value from config file declared in etc folder.
Something like this:

```
<pollEnrich uri="file:inbox?fileName=data.txt" timeout="{{readTimeout}}"/>
```

While doing so, I am getting  the following error:

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException : cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '{{readTimeout}}' is not a valid value for 'integer'

This error only comes for pollenrich and nowhere else in my code. I am able to use other properties from config file in the same camel-context.
e.g.,

```
<from uri="timer://TestTimer?period={{timer.interval}}&amp;delay={{startupDelay}}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation at: http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html at the section titled *Using property placeholders for any kind of attribute in the XML DSL*

Comment: Read that documentation I linked to!